# Correct behavior of different sized output, wire in verilog?

Tags: verilog

So I have something like this:

```
module top (..., out,...);
...
output [0:1] out;
wire [0:3] out;
...
endmodule
```

Is this correct verilog? If so, is the correct behavior of this a 2 bit out port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verilog 2001 quick reference guide (section 5.2) says this:

```
• Port/data type connection rules:
The port range and data type range must be the same (if different, some
software tools will use the data type size instead of reporting an error).
```

So I'll say it's not correct.